# Hough Transform Implementation for Set of Points

Tags: python, hough-transform, astronomy

Trying to use the Hough transform to detect lines in what is effectively a scatterplot of thousands of points (detections in telescope exposures). All the available python modules I have found so far are for images. Perhaps, the only solution is to convert the scatterplot to an image that can then be read by the available tools or run Hough transform directly on the array of points?

How can I use the Hough transform on a scatter plot?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  In particular, we work with focused, specific questions on programming; a request for an off-site resource is specifically off-topic.

Comment: @Prune, I am confused as to how this is a request for an off-site resource. I want to include the Hough transform in my program, but don't know how to do so for a sparse scattering of points, rather than an image

Comment: From context, I took this as a request for a module or other tool that *does* handle the problem.  If not, then the nebulous "any suggestions" is simply too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your scatter plot into a density plot. This can be done by binning your data points using a 2d histogram

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(size=1000)

counts, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=30)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(counts)
plt.show()
```

`xedges` and `yedges` are the coordinates of each bin, and `counts` contains the number of data points in each bin. You can then run the Hough Transform of your choice on `counts`.